# What are the different styles of Japanese Saws

Tags: hand-tools, hand-saw, traditional-techniques

Pretty much just what the title says. I would like to know the different styles of Japanese saws and what each one is designed for. I am aware of Dozuki and Ryoba but I will assume there are others.

Comment: If the downvoter would be happy to explain the reasoning I could try and fix the question. This seems fairly straightforward to me as it stands. We are allowed to ask questions like this. Even encouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dōzuki (胴付(鋸))   A type of backsaw. The Japanese means "attached
>   trunk", thus a saw with a stiffening strip attached, i.e., a backsaw.
>
> Ryōba (両刃)   Multi-purpose carpentry saw with two cutting edges. The
>   Japanese means "double blade". There is a cross-cutting (yokobiki)
>   blade on one side and a ripping (tatebiki) blade on the other.
>
> Azebiki (あぜ引き)   A small ryōba saw used for cutting into the flat
>   surface of a board rather than from the edge. The blade has a convex
>   curve which can begin the cut anywhere on the surface.
>
> Mawashibiki (回し引き)   A thin saw used for cutting curves, the Japanese
>   version of a keyhole saw. The name means "turning cut".

The text is copied with pride from [Wikipedia/Japanese saw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_saw).

Comment: @bowlturner nice pick-up on the edit.

Comment: You translated all but one of the Japanese terms which got me curious so I looked it up. Apparently あぜ means a ridge or notch, so あぜ引き means ridge-cutting or notch-cutting.